# Setting the background of a UILabel (transparency problem with .png files)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilabel

I'm trying to set the background of a UILabel by setting its property `backgroundColor`.

But I have a problem: the backgroundColor is created from a .png file (with transparency) and the result is that the transparent part appear in black.

Any solution without the need of custom subclasses?

**Update**

I tried setting the UILabel property `opaque` to `NO` but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you might have forgotten to change the opaque property of the UILabel:

```
label.opaque = NO;
```

Alternatively, you can set this property in the InterfaceBuilder view of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and the solution is:

```
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Changing opaque or alpha value didn't work.

Comment: In my situation, changing Opaque did nothing, but setting a clear background color worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this one:

```
[your_label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change its `opaque` property to `NO`.

---

If it doesn't help, you can add imageView behing your label:

```
[yourLabel setOpaque:NO];
[yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
UIImageView *labelBkg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:yourLabel.frame];
[labelBkg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName.png"]];
[self.view insertSubview:labelBkg belowSubview:yourLabel];
[labelBkg release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to save it as a png24 or 24bit png file - at least that's the case when saving from PhotoShop

Answer (score 0):

```
[footer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Favourite_商品文字背景.png"]]];
[footer setOpaque:NO];
```

it must be work,goodLuck!